# Dynamic anchor tag onclick is not calling server function

Tags: c#, anchor

I am trying to create anchor tags whose onClick fire a server side function. But this is not working. Also I want to pass some parameters whose value takes from db.

```
html.Append("<tr id='" + evidenceID + "'>" +
                                        "<td><a id='" + titleId + "' href='#' runat='server' OnClick='StreamVideoCall('" + parameters + "')'>" + myDeserializedObjList[item].attributes.title + "</a></td>" +
                                        "<td>" + myDeserializedObjList[item].attributes.recordedOn + "</td>"+
                                        "<td id='t" + item + "'>" + owner + "</td></tr>");
```

I tried  asp:Hyperlink. But doesn't work. Can anyone please help me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating this control list that is `table` from your server code, then better use the `Table Control` and add each row and column based on your database table

In the specified table cell you have to create `HtmlAnchor` or `HyperLink` control as you wish and add it to `table cell` control collection.

then add this table control created in server code to any div that is set `runat = server` in html source

EDIT

You may refer this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7bewx260.aspx) to see how dynamically add table row and cell to a table control.

event handler to the dynamic anchor control can added using
`anch.OnClick += eventhandler;`